# onChange the domain of a m2o field in a child model depending on anoter m2o field in the parent model odoo13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have two models (parent and child) with mutual m2o filed(analytic account id). I want to filter the value of the field in the child based on the selected value in the parent ( I want the value to be the same). I have tried to do it using on change but it doesn't work so far. Here is my code:

```
class logistic(models.Model):
    _name = 'logistic.logistic'
    _inherit = ['portal.mixin', 'mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']
    _description = 'logistic.logistic'
    _order = 'id desc'

    additional_services_ids = fields.One2many('additional.service.line', 'waybill_id', 
           string='Services lines')
    analytic_account_id = fields.Many2one('account.analytic.account', string='Analytic Account', 
         index=True,required=True)


    @api.onchange('analytic_account_id')
    def _analytic_account_id(self):
        for rec in self:
            return {'domain': {
                'additional_services_ids.analytic_account_id': [('analytic_account_id', '=', 
                 rec.analytic_account_id.id)]}}

class AdditionalServicesLine(models.Model):
    _name = "additional.service.line"
    _description = "Additional services"

   
    waybill_id = fields.Many2one('logistic.logistic', string='Additional Services Entry')
    analytic_account_id = fields.Many2one('account.analytic.account', string='Analytic Account', 
           index=True,required=True)
```

Comment: What about making it related to the parent? `analytic_account_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="account.analytic.account", related="waybill_id.analytic_account_id", store=True, index=True, readonly=True)`

Comment: ok I will give it a shot